# Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio just updated itself to 0.4.2, and now fails parsing my project with the message:

> Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9. If using the
>   gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl...

I tried various things and now it's all messed up. Kind of confused what's going on here, one should think Android Studio knows which Gradle (whatever that is) version it has/had installed?!

Is it perhaps my project which declared a dependency on 1.8, which it can no longer find due to the Studio update updating its gradle to 1.9, without also updating the existing project dependency from 1.8 to 1.9?

Answer (score 5):

Update **distributionUrl** mentioned in your **YOUR_PROJECT/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties** file, Studio(0.4.2) should automatically prompt for auto fix while gradle sync but if it didn't do it manually. distributionUrl should be like

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

Update all **build.gradle** files inside your project or if you are using top level build.gradle file for defining gradle version update in that only with

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
```

Android Studio(0.4.2) only supports Gradle 1.9 which can be defined using **gradle:0.7.+** in dependency classpath.

Answer (score 1):

In your project root is a gradle folder. Within that folder is a file 'gradle-wrapper.properties' open that file in a text editor and change the version in the distributionUrl from 1.8 to 1.9.

Then re-open your project.

Comment: The distributionUrl is already pointing to gradle-1.9-all.zip, something else must be going wrong. :(

Comment: The distributionUrl is already pointing to gradle-1.9-all.zip. However, changing it from 1.9 to 1.8 seems to get the compilation a bit further, until I'm met with yet another error message (1.8 no longer supported) but clicking the "Fix by re-importing" link made the project build again.