# Compiler error on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a android studio project that have two compile error.

First Error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hello:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Second Error:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

Comment: Which version of studio are you on ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294417/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-9/21301099#21301099

Comment: my version is AI-130.677228

Comment: you are using very old version of studio I recommand you to update it to latest version.