# import old gradle project into new android studio version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So after a fresh OS install I installed the newest Version of Android Studio and tried to import an old project.

If I try to build it i get the message:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project '<name>' Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.9.  Please fix the project's Gradle settings. Gradle settings
```

Ok it isn't downwards compatible but how i fix it? Why it does no automatically build with the newest version?

If i look up the Gradle Settings the Service directory Path is the C:/Users//.gradle
and under ./.gradle there are several directorys with 1.6 and 1.9 folders.

Can any one give me the hint?

kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294417/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-9/21301099#21301099

Comment: Does not fix it. "20:25:45 ExternalSystemException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9.zip'.

Comment: make sure you are connected to internet to download the gradle for first time.

Comment: I'm connected. Everything is up to date (SDK Manager) and I installed the latest android studio version.

Comment: Can you include the new issue along with your gradle-wrapper.properties file in the question so I can answer.

Comment: I created a fresh Project then copied my old project into the Android Studio project folder. Imported this project. Changed DistributionURL in gradle.wrapper.propertise to gradle-1.9-all.zip then I get a "Failed to refresh Gradle project 'ITS_Calc' Cause: failed to find target android-17 but everything is installed. If I change the build.gradle to the old classpath  "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'" I get the old error with "
> Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.9"

Comment: Actually I have placed wrong gradle distribution url in my answer. please check the updated answer from url in my first comment and let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: include your build.gradle files in the question to answer. Avoid putting long comments with new question in comments.

Comment: Now it is everything like in your answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294417/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-9/21301099#21301099. I saved the project, closed it, deleted it, imported it new and now i get the same Error. "Failed to refresh Gradle project 'ITS_Calc' Cause: failed to find target android-17  Please install the missing platform from the Android SDK Manager. Open Android SDK Manager"

Answer (score 1):

As the issue requires some more description adding some points here.

Do the mentioned below along with the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294417/gradle-version-1-8-is-required-current-version-is-1-9/21301099#21301099

Download the latest build-tools from Android SDK Manager, Its is 19.0.1 as of now.

Now change

```
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
```

In your build.gradle file and do sync your project with gradle.

Comment: Thanks. I also changed the  compileSdkVersion to 19 and synced. Now it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

my gradle.wrapper.propertise

```
    #Wed Feb 12 18:43:44 CET 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```